# How to order bars within all facets?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, facet-wrap

This question is following my (now deleted) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51708936/how-to-order-a-column-of-my-dataframe-according-to-another-variable).

This is my data :

```
i <- data.frame(
nbr =c(15.18 ,11.53 ,13.37 ,9.2, 10.9, 12.23 ,9.53, 9.81, 7.86, 12.79,
 22.03 ,17.64 ,18.1, 16.78 ,17.53 ,16.97 ,17.76 ,18.35 ,12.82 ,20.91,
 22.09 ,19.18 ,17.54 ,18.45 ,19.83 ,16.99 ,19.69 ,19.45 ,13.07 ,21.41,
 12.13 ,9.76, 10.79 ,10.74 ,12.43 ,9.65, 12.18 ,11.63 ,6.74, 12.31,
 17.5, 14.75 ,15.2, 13.89 ,15.24 ,17.43 ,15.22 ,14.04,9.49, 15.86,
 8.09, 5.86, 6.68, 7.34, 8.01, 6.35, 8.4, 7.4, 3.88, 6.92 ),
x2=rep(c("a",  "b",   "c",  "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"),6),
s = c(rep(c(rep(c("3"),10),
                    rep(c("4"),10),
                    rep(c("5"),10),
                    rep(c("6"),10),
                    rep(c("7"),10),
                    rep(c("8"),10)),1)))
```

I want to order bars from all my facets in ascending order according to my variable "nbr".
I tried :

```
ii <- i[order(i$s, i$nbr ), ]
sn <- factor(x = 1:60, labels = ii$x2)
ii$sn <- sn
ggplot(data = ii, aes(x = sn , y = nbr)) + 
  facet_wrap(. ~ s, ncol=2,scale='free_x')+   geom_bar(stat = 'identity')+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=.5,colour='gray50'))
```

It works only for one facet (the first groupe = "3") and the x-axis of the other facet takes the same order as the x-axis of the first facet !

[image]

Comment: Cannot reproduce the line 'sn <- factor(x = 1:60, labels = ii$x2)' - I get the error Error in `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels,  : 
  factor level [11] is duplicated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a discussion regarding this issue  [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1902), which they proposed the below two functions as a solution to this problem which you can find [here](https://github.com/dgrtwo/drlib/blob/master/R/reorder_within.R).

```
scale_x_reordered <- function(..., sep = "___") {
  reg <- paste0(sep, ".+$")
  ggplot2::scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) gsub(reg, "", x), ...)
}

reorder_within <- function(x, by, within, fun = mean, sep = "___", ...) {
  new_x <- paste(x, within, sep = sep)
  stats::reorder(new_x, by, FUN = fun)
}


ggplot(ii, aes(reorder_within(sn, nbr, s), nbr)) +
     geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
     scale_x_reordered() +
     facet_wrap(.~ s, ncol=2,scales = "free_x") + 
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=.5,colour='gray50'))
```

[image]